# can't install openjdk keeps giving me error

Tags: openjdk

I tried installing openjdk-9 but for some reason it keeps giving me error

Here's the commands i have tried.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f` ?

Comment: yes I have, I try that and it gives me another error

Comment: If nothing just purge openjdk-9-jre openjdk-9-jdk and reinstall them

Comment: how to do that safely because I don't want to mess up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try reinstalling them cleanly.

`sudo apt-get purge openjdk-9-jre openjdk-9-jdk`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install -f`

now I don't know which one you need, probably only the jre if you need the jdk install only the jdk (that means openjdk-9-jdk)

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jre`

Comment: it still keeps giving me error about unmet dependencies, Here is the image about the commands i put in and the error it gives me http://imgur.com/MOis3DS

Comment: also add to the purge command the openjdk-9-demo openjdk-9-jdk-headless openjdk-9-source

Comment: The commands you told me to add worked like a charm, thank you so much, I highly appreciate your help.